# Is there a word for nice or okay that isn't "bona"?

Tags: adjectives

From what I understand, whenever you want to say 'nice' in English, this can be done with *bona*, but this always sounds very jarring in my head. *Bona* seems to give whatever I am trying to call 'nice' more positive energy than I intend with the word *nice*, along with the fact that *nice* seems different from *good* in English. Is there a way to make a distinction between *nice* and *good*?

The word *nice* means, in my mind, something that is pleasing, but is just that. I hope that kinda helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*plaĉa* - something that is pleasing, pleasant

*agrabla* - good, nice, pleasant

*ĉarma* - charming, nice

Answer (score 2):

If *bona* is too strong, you can tone it down with the diminutive: *boneta*.

- *boneta* - nice
- *bona* - good
- *bonega* - great